# Can I pass dynamic variables to placeholders that are defined in the msgstr, but not in the msgid in Django i18n?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

In Django I have a `.po` file that contains translations in this format:

```
msgid "delete-comment-description"
msgstr "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?"
```

There are also translations that require a dynamic value:

```
msgid "hello-user-title"
msgstr "Hello, %(user)s. I hope you are fine."
```

How can I pass the variable `user` to use `hello-user-title` in a template?

I've tried things like:

```
{% blocktranslate with user="my_username" %}
hello-user-title
{% endblocktranslate %}
```

and

```
{% translate "hello-user-title" user="my_username" %}
```

But both are not working.

The reason the msgid is more of a variable name is because this  application is partly in React and partly in Django. React is leading for most frontend parts, but some parts are generated by Django templates.